# SQL - COUNT columns from separate tables based on a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I'm still learning SQL and this is part of my assignment. I'm not just looking for the answers but I would like to understand how to tackle this as I'm stumped as to what to even search for online.

Part of the assignment we are given a question and an example output. We have to insert data to tables we have created and write a SQL query that will return results that answer the question.

This particular question goes something like:
"For each office, display its suburb, the name of the manager, the total number of staff (excluding the manager) in the office, and the number of listings that are for sale."

There are 3 tables involved (I removed unnecessary columns):

- Office (**id**, *office_manager_id*, office_suburb)
- Staff (**id**, *office_id*)
- Listing (**id**, *office_id*, *staff_id*, *buyer_id*)

The output example is something like:

```
Office Suburb |  Manager  |  No. of Staff  |  No of Listing for Sale  |
  New York    |  Johnny   |      2         |         5                |
```

I figured I could do this with a COUNT and GROUP BY, but as soon as I try to join 3 tables and use COUNT, the number of rows just goes crazy and so my count for 'No. of Staff' and 'No. of Listing for Sale' becomes the same.

If I count them separately (only using 2 tables, e.g. Office and Listing or Office and Staff) then I am able to get the desired COUNT output.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT 
    o.office_suburb AS "Office Suburb", 
    (s.first_name || ' ' || s.last_name) AS "Manager",
    COUNT(s.salary)-1 AS "No. of Staff", 
    COUNT(l.id) AS "No. of Listings for Sale"
FROM staff s, office o, listing l
WHERE o.id = s.office_id 
    AND s.id = o.office_manager_id 
    AND o.id = l.office_id 
    AND s.id = l.staff_id
    AND l.buyer_id IS NULL
GROUP BY o.office_suburb, s.first_name, s.last_name
```

If anyone could help me with the direction I would appreciate it. I tried searching for terms like 'count multiple tables', 'group by with 3 tables', etc with no luck. Even if you could help with something like: 'just search xyz, that's what you need', I would so appreciate that...

Thank you.

PS: The way we learnt how to join tables was to use the WHERE clause, which is why my SQL is using WHERE instead of JOIN. Also this is all done in Oracle ApEx.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  If you are taking a course, why is it not teaching proper SQL syntax?

Comment: why does `l.buyer_id` has to be `NULL` in your result? It is not written in your question that you want all the listings of all buyer ids that are null, that is why i am asking.

Comment: Yes I do agree with the JOINs, I was also a bit puzzled why JOIN was not taught... But I have been looking up JOINs and fortunately it's not as complicated (at least INNER JOINS).

With regards to buyer_id being NULL, that is mainly because I need to get listings that are still on sale which means the buyer_id for that listing record will be NULL (until the property is sold, which would then have a buyer_id against the listing record).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend correlated subqueries, but like this:

```
SELECT o.office_suburb, (sm.first_name || ' ' || sm.last_name) AS Manager,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM staff s2
        WHERE s2.office_id = o.id
       ) as num_staff,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM listings l
        WHERE l.office_id = o.id AND l.buyer_id IS NULL
       ) as num_listings
FROM office o JOIN
     staff sm
     ON sm.id = o.office_manager_id ;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Also, `GROUP BY` is not needed in the outer query.

Comment: Oh my, this is brilliant. I didn't know you can do subqueries in the SELECT part of the query. I thought subqueries can only be added in the WHERE clause bit. (e.g. WHERE xyz = (subquery).

Thank you for this. I've tried this and it works! It's also very similar to what I was thinking before (was able to get the correct counts using subqueries but only for staff count OR listing count, couldn't do it with both staff count and listing count).

I've learnt something new! :) Really appreciative of this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The point is that each `office` has a unique `id` per `office_manager` and `office_suburb` so something like the following would help. Since my initial answer was wrong, i have to edit accordingly. You can use `JOIN` as in the following query.

```
SELECT
o2.office_suburb AS "Office Suburb",
(s2.first_name || ' ' || s2.last_name) AS "Manager",
p.csid AS "No. of Staff", 
p.clid AS "No. of Listings for Sale" 
FROM
(SELECT 
    o.id,
    COUNT(s.id) AS csid, 
    COUNT(l.id) AS clid
FROM office o
JOIN staff s ON (o.id = s.office_id)
JOIN listing l ON (o.id = l.office_id AND s.id = l.staff_id)
WHERE l.staff_id <> o.office_manager_id AND l.buyer_id IS NULL
GROUP BY o.id) p
JOIN office o2 ON p.id = o2.id
JOIN staff s2 ON s2.id = o2.office_manager_id AND s2.office_id = o2.id
```

You could check the result in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49cc4/18)

Comment: With this, I get a 'ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression' error.
When I change the GROUP BY to include s.first_name and s.last_name I get no data found.
If I removed the l.staff_id <> o.office_manager_id part, I do get a result but it returns the same result as I was getting. The count for Staff and Listings are the same.

I was able to get to the solution using @Gordon Linoff's solution. Using Subqueries in the SELECT part of the query.

Comment: @YeboMate if you want an alternative answer this one is ok.

Comment: @YeboMate PS: the above query will not get you listings that belong to office managers and it will not include managers in the count of staff of an office.